# паддинг удаляет тень у виджета?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ui

[image: example of shadow erasing]

Привет!

Если я раскомментирую второй текстовый виджет, тени пропадут с двух сторон (как на скриншоте) у этого и других!! виджетов на этом экране, если второй текстовый виджет закомментирован, то тени отображаются со всех четырех сторон хорошо как и должно быть у этого и у других виджетов на этом экране, я не могу понять как такое может быть вообще. Это выглядет будто внешний паддинг удаляет эти тени, но я не трогаю паддинг, он там всегда, я просто раскомментировываю второй текст виджет.

```dart
  return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            spreadRadius: 0.05,
            blurRadius: 7.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Text(
            'random text',
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          // Text(
          //   'random text 2',
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: На [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: спасибо, поправил!

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Widget Inspector в DevTools. Через него сможете выяснить, какой виджет обрезает тень